# Unusual table to parse

Tags: python, parsing

How do I parse this type of tables?

https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt

```
                     The First 10,000 Primes
                    (the 10,000th is 104,729)
     For more information on primes see http://primes.utm.edu/

  2      3      5      7     11     13     17     19     23     29 
 31     37     41     43     47     53     59     61     67     71 
 73     79     83     89     97    101    103    107    109    113
```

These are not comma separated or xml structured numbers. Do you know any way to, say, read them into a list?

Comment: In future, please include some sample data from the external reference site as well as the link to the original — as in the edited version.  (I note that there are 4 extra spaces at the start of each line that are 'swallowed' by SO's MarkDown processing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the structure of the table just by knowing your data starts at the fourth line and ends one line before the end. Furthermore, the whole table has integer contents. For example:

```
    # Using the requests HTTP client library
    import requests
    # Get data from HTTP request
    data = requests.get("http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt").text
    # Nested list comprehension: Split data into lines, consider from fourth line to second last, then split those lines into columns which will be evaluated as integers.
    [[int(e) for e in l.strip().split()] for l in data.split('\n')[4:-2]]
```

Voilà.

This works because the implicit split method will split on whitespaces such as tabs, group of spaces, etc.